# How to use other than default database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, sqlite

I am creating a project that supports multiple databases. I have written queries in models, and I need to save those details in a selected database.

I have two databases: SQLite3 and MongoDB. Now I need to save those query details in SQLite3. How do I do it? I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.5.4.

Here is the code in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {},

'sqlite':
 {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'mydb.sqlite3'),

    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
 },

 'mongodb':
 {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME': "mydb",                   

    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '', 
    'PORT': '', 
 }

}
```

And here is the code in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tagline = models.TextField()
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`using` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save) if you use `save` method.

```
blog = Blog(name='This is a blog post', tagline='python django')
blog.save(using='sqlite')
```

or use [`db_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases) if you use `create` method:

```
blog = Blog.objects.db_manager('sqlite').create(
    name='This is a blog post', tagline='python django')
```

For other operations, see [Multiple databases - Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/).

Comment: it says                                                                                                                "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details".what i did wrong...?

Comment: @Shiva, `default` setting is empty. Choose one of `sqlite` or `mongodb` as a default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,But if i put mongodb as default database,I think it will take default database and saving the content in mongodb

Comment: @Shiva, That's right. That's what `default` mean in computer. If you want to save to non-default database use `using`, `db_manager` as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Shiva, `do it` what? If you mean, always write/read from sqlite, set `sqlite` as deafult. If you mean other thing, I have no idea.

Comment: [Please accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if this answer solved your problem.  And post a separated question if you have another question.

Comment: ,Sorry boss. Up to now i dont know how to accept.Now Accepted